# Buscador de un array de objetos con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código que busca en un array la información que inserto en el input, en este caso el código funciona muy bien

```js
function autocompletado () {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';

   var preguntame = ["qwe", "ert", "tyu", "uio", "opa", "asd", "fgh", "hjk", "jkl", "xcz", "rt", "sdf"];

    var pal = document.getElementById("buscar-pal").value;
    var tam = pal.length;
    for(indice in preguntame){
    var nombre = preguntame[indice];
    if(pal.length != 0 && nombre.length != 0){
     if(nombre.toLowerCase().search(pal.toLowerCase()) != -1){
      var node = document.createElement("li");
      node.innerHTML = "<a href="+preguntame[0].name+">"+preguntame[indice]+"</a>";
      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="buscar-pal" onkeyup="autocompletado()" style="border: solid 2px">
 <div>
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
 </div>
```

pero claramente no me sirve este código cuando tengo un array de objetos como este

```
 var preguntame = [
        {nombre: 'manzanas', cantidad: 2},
        {nombre: 'bananas', cantidad: 0},
        {nombre: 'cerezas', cantidad: 5}
    ];
```

la verdad llevo muy poco tiempo usando javascript y no he encontrado la forma de hacer la búsqueda a este tipo de array

agradecería mucho cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es muy similar a tu codigo.  Algo asi:

```js
function autocompletado () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';

 var preguntame = [
        {nombre: 'manzanas', cantidad: 2},
        {nombre: 'bananas', cantidad: 0},
        {nombre: 'cerezas', cantidad: 5}
    ];

 var pal = document.getElementById("buscar-pal").value;
 var tam = pal.length;
 for(indice in preguntame){
     var item = preguntame[indice];
            var nombre = item.nombre;
     if(pal.length != 0 && nombre.length != 0){
   if(nombre.toLowerCase().search(pal.toLowerCase()) != -1){
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    node.innerHTML = "<a href="+nombre+">"+nombre+"</a>";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
   }
     }
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="buscar-pal" onkeyup="autocompletado()" style="border: solid 2px">
 <div>
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
 </div>
```